# Photo demographic targeting in Craft?

Tags: image

We will be creating a website for a large clinical trial. The catch is that this trial will have study sites in many different areas of the world. We want to appeal to use user depending on their demographic. For example, when a user from one of our Thailand sites visits the website, we want them to see photos of Asian study participants (from photos we provide). Is this a possibility? It would sort of be like text translation but with photos instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is possible using the standard Craft Pro "locale" stuff. In addition to making text translatable, you can make Assets translatable - in which case you can upload a different image for each translated region. The appropriate asset will be used. This assumes you target each region by having a dedicated URL prefix for each (mysite.com/thailand, mysite.com/japan etc)

https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Craft Geo Plugin for a project previously and it worked really well. It allowed us to serve specific content to detectable regions and areas, so that sounds like what you're after:

https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-geo

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! Did it serve up that specific content automatically or did you have to re-direct it to a different domain or URL?

Comment: No problem @LAS87 We used the tags in an if statement on a template to decide which version of content to show, but you could equally use the country code to form an image URL for example.